# Install a package via nfs server

Tags: package-management, nfs

i want to install acl package to the instances(more than 10) on google cloud platform, they are connected to a nfs server. Is it possible to install it trough the nfs server. if it is not possible i have to install one by one.

Comment: do you have the ssh keys of all your instances on the nfs server?

Comment: yes i have, i can connect all of them. i can even use the tmux-cssh to install a package but i'm looking for another way specially nfs.

Comment: nfs can't do that. You could script the whole process, with a for loop